# _.debounce check if the debounce is pending

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there any way to check if debounce function is pending?

By the use of source analysis I found only two methods: `flush` and `cancel`.

Answer (score 4):

### Update 1

`debounce`'s `pending` method is only accessible on `master` branch of `lodash`. Other branches (every package has its own branch - `es` for `lodash-es`, etc.) does not have this revision of `debounce`, so it seems like this feature is not released yet. Example - [npm branch](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/c4b20a6ea7f5722ed04d2c1fe9744ebd10ebd864/debounce.js#L187)

I tried to use exact this revision and `pending` method is working as expected. Here is my `packages.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "git://github.com/lodash/lodash.git#51c562256bc2a021eee05699444ce5a4db2df698"
  }
}
```

And `index.js`:

```
const fn = debounce(() => console.log('BOOM!'), 1000)
fn()
console.log(fn.pending())
```

Output of `>node ./index.js` is:

```
true
BOOM!
```

The second line is an actual log of debounced function, appears after the timeout. One thing to note - sources are in ES Modules, so you have to transpile them, or mjs-ify, or rewrite to require's.

### Initial answer

There is a `pending` method for this. Both `debounce` and `throttle` should have such method. [Sources for debounce](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/51c562256bc2a021eee05699444ce5a4db2df698/debounce.js#L208)

But I couldn't use it as described! :P

For now, we're managing such state manually, just some boolean flag somewhere around.

Comment: @QueueOverflow I updated the answer. PS: if someone aware of any online dev env w/ support of `package.json` we can reproduce this, so people don't have to struggle with the local setup. Repl.it seems to support `package.json`, but there is no `git` executable, so our package source is not supported :(

Comment: Should be part of Lodash v5 (which will probably never be released): https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5146